# Nested ndarray reshape

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have a problem,i am working with tensorflow keras for classification.
For this i loaded images with skimage.io and store it into pandas dataframe.
Now the problem is that i have **ndarrays of shape(160,160)** within **ndarray of shape (520,).**
Now, i want to convert this to shape(520,160,160).I tried reshape method

```
array = np.array(df.image)
array.reshape(520,160,160)
```

This code give me error:
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 520 into shape (520,160,160)

Comment: If `array` is your outer array, try `array.flatten().reshape((520,160,160))`

Comment: Same error, ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 520 into shape (520,160,160)

Comment: What is df.image?

Comment: `array = np.stack(df.image)` instead?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, thank you for solution, it worked!

Comment: Seemed like you found the issue just before my comment on your own ;)